# Click event on ImageView inside TableCell in JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx, imageview, tableview

I have a JavaFX `TableView` populated with many `TableColumns`, one of which is `matImageColumn`. The code for it looks like:

```
matImageColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<CustomObject, ImageView>, TableCell<CustomObject, ImageView>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell call(final TableColumn<CustomObject, ImageView> param) {
        final TableCell<CustomObject, ImageView> cell = new TableCell<CustomObject, ImageView>() {
            ImageView img = new ImageView();

            @Override
            public void updateItem(ImageView item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    CustomObject co = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                    img = co.getImageViewOfMat();

                    setGraphic(img);
                    setText(null);
                }
            }            
        };
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Now as it is, I am looking to include a  click event on my imageview but I am clueless from where to start.Can you show me possible solutions to this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing `ImageView item` and `CustomObject co = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());` is probably incorrect. As for your question, I don't see why you can't do `img.setOnMouseClicked(...);`.

Comment: don't use nodes as data! And provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, please.

Comment: I have thought about it, however top layer is of course cell therefore the event is never consumed. @Sedrick You are right about co and iv approach, fixed it.

Comment: @kleopatra I think I have found solution now, will test it.